Override Entity Framework Core circular dependency
I have the table structure (simplified):
public class Record 
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<StatusInstance> StatusInstances { get; set; } = default!;
    public Guid? CurrentStatusId { get; set; } = default!;
    public virtual StatusInstance CurrentStatus { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class StatusInstance
{
    public Guid? RecordId { get; set; }   
}

I would like to add to both list and single instance. I have similar tables that i would also like to work this way but obviously this results in a circular dependency warning.
What i have tried and works:

I can add the record with currentstatus but don't add to list or add recordId. I can then add subsequent new status after the record is created but the first status is lost.
I can add the record without any status in either list or current, then add to both after the initial save, however due to the unique way app works this is not possible.
I could remove the current status and store everything in list, however due to the way i am using entity framework i need a property with a one to one relationship. I can setup in record to select first status as a property however I need to get full list to do this then select first. Don't want to retrieve full list to do this.

As it seems possible to get around circular dependency issues by saving in a particular order, I'm sure there must be a way to do it on first save. All though i can find aways around it, it would be very convenient to this relationship throughout the system.
For reference i have this code in OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
    .HasOne(r => r.CurrentStatus)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Record>(r => r.CurrentStatusId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
    .HasMany(r => r.StatusInstances)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.RecordId);


EF deals with objects, not tables, and infers relations. There's no problem having a Post.Blog property and a Blog.Posts at the same time. That's the very example used in the EF Core Quickstart. Have you tried removing the HasOne and HasMany ? You don't even need RecordId and CurrentStatusId, these can be inferred and generated as shadow properties

Thanks for the reply, Yes, tried without the code in OnModelCreating, this causes EF core to create foreign keys but in only 1 direction. Hence why I have added them. In the example I can't see Post.Blog & Post.Blogs simlar to my situation

This is a well-know chicken-and-egg problem.

It is also a poor data relationship design. You intend that CurrentStatus would reference one of the StatusInstances in the associated collection, but there is no way to enforce that. The currentStatusId could very well point to a StatusInstance that is associated with a completely different RecordId. A safer alternative is an IsCurrent flag or maintaining an order on the StatusInstance.  (A trigger can be used to auto-deselect isCurrent on all other instances for the record when you set it to true on one.)

@TomKnevitt you didn't say anything about migrations, which is the only thing that can create foreign key constraints. FKs are constraints, not relations. The database itself prevents you from defining a circular FK reference, not EF. Trying to delete a "parent" row would be blocked by the FK constraints from all child rows to the parent. and vice versa The database would force you to specify a CASCADE option, to either delete the child rows or set the FK columns to NULL
